# Angular service error handling responseType = blob

Tags: angular, error-handling

I'm handling errors in Angular service (I have method that download file but during error I return json with text of error).

`FileService` method:

```
downloadRaw(id: string, revision: number = 0): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob> | JsonError> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('revision', revision.toString());

    return this.http
      .get(this.downloadRawFileUrl
        .replace(':id', id),
        {
          observe: 'response',
          responseType: 'blob',
          params: params 
        })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorService.handleError)
      );
  }
```

component method:

```
downloadFile(fileGUID: string) {
    this.fileService.downloadRaw(fileGUID).subscribe(
      (response: (HttpResponse<Blob> | JsonError)) => {
        if ((<JsonError>response).errors == undefined) {
          let fileName = (<HttpResponse<Blob>>response).headers.get('File-Name');
          const downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(<Blob>(<HttpResponse<Blob>>response).body);
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = downloadURL;
          link.download = <string>fileName;
          link.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is my `ErrorService`:

```
export class ErrorService {
    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }

    handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<JsonError> {
        let jsonError: JsonError = new JsonError();
        if(error.error instanceof Blob) {
            this.getJsonError(error).then((response: JsonError) => {
                jsonError = response;
                this.showToastr(jsonError);
                return of(response);
            });
        } else {
            jsonError = error.error;
            this.showToastr(jsonError);
        }
        
        return of(jsonError);
    }

    getJsonError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Promise<JsonError> {
        return error.error.text().then((text: string) => {
            let jsonError = JSON.parse(text);
            return jsonError;
        });
    }

    showToastr(jsonError: JsonError): void {
        for (const er of jsonError.errors) {
            this.toastr.error(er.message, er.title);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getJsonError')` into component this line of code:

```
this.fileService.downloadRaw(fileGUID).subscribe(
```

Maybe something with wrong type of return?
What am I doing wrong? And maybe how can I simplify this service?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce this in an online code editor such as Stackblitz, since I don't see why this wouldn't work from this code alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the way you call error service method:

```
catchError(error=>this.errorService.handleError(error))
```

So, instead of a service method, pass a function to `catchError` that takes error as an argument, and then pass the error to the service instead.

When passing service method to `catchError`, it uses the service method as a selector function, but then it creates a new instances of internal classes, like seen here: https://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operators/catchError.js.html#lineNumber60, so `this` no longer references service, so service method cannot be called

Comment: Excellent! This works, but why it doesn't work as in Angular docs? https://angular.io/guide/http-handle-request-errors

Comment: well, cannot find exactly why it happens when looking at [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError), but when used like that, logging `this` reads `CatchSubscriber`, and not the service instance, hence the error when using `this.method`.. the example from the docs would behave the same, i.e. wouldn't be able to call instance methods

Comment: I think it uses the service method as a selector function, but then it creates a new instance from it here: https://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operators/catchError.js.html#lineNumber60